# Count occurrence of string values per row in dataframe in R (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to count the number of occurrences of select string values per row in a dataframe. Ideally, this would be completed using the `dplyr` package.

Here is a dataframe similar to the one I am working with:

```
df <- tibble(
  d1 = c('b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
  d2 = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
  d3 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'),
  d4 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'd'),
  d5 = c('a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
  d6 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'a'),
  d7 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
  d8 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a')
)
```

I would like to be able to define the columns that I am counting over:

```
cols <- c('d2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6', 'd7', 'd8')
```

I would also like to define the strings I am searching for:

```
bcde <- c('b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
```

Thus far, I have been able to identify that one of the strings in `bcde` is present in one of cols `d2:d8`, per row, using the following code:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    d9 = case_when(
      if_any(all_of(cols), ~ . %in% bcde) ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0)
  )
```

Which produces:

```
  d1    d2    d3    d4    d5    d6    d7    d8       d9
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 b     a     a     a     a     a     a     a         0
2 a     a     a     a     c     a     a     a         1
3 a     b     a     a     a     a     a     a         1
4 a     a     c     a     a     b     a     a         1
5 a     a     a     a     a     a     a     a         0
6 a     a     b     a     a     a     a     a         1
7 a     a     a     a     a     d     a     a         1
8 a     a     a     d     a     a     a     a         1
```

However, I would like to produce:

```
  d1    d2    d3    d4    d5    d6    d7    d8       d9
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 b     a     a     a     a     a     a     a         0
2 a     a     a     a     c     a     a     a         1
3 a     b     a     a     a     a     a     a         1
4 a     a     c     a     a     b     a     a         2
5 a     a     a     a     a     a     a     a         0
6 a     a     b     a     a     a     a     a         1
7 a     a     a     a     a     d     a     a         1
8 a     a     a     d     a     a     a     a         1
```

(i.e. count the number of occurrences if a string in `bcde` in cols `d2:d8`, rather than merely check for their presence).

I am unsure how to proceed by incorporating a counting function whilst looping through the dataframe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `across` with `rowSums` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(d9 = rowSums(across(all_of(cols), `%in%`, bcde)))

#  d1    d2    d3    d4    d5    d6    d7    d8       d9
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 b     a     a     a     a     a     a     a         0
#2 a     a     a     a     c     a     a     a         1
#3 a     b     a     a     a     a     a     a         1
#4 a     a     c     a     a     b     a     a         2
#5 a     a     a     a     a     a     a     a         0
#6 a     a     b     a     a     a     a     a         1
#7 a     a     a     a     a     d     a     a         1
#8 a     a     a     d     a     a     a     a         1
```

This can also be written in base R -

```
df$d9 <- rowSums(sapply(df[cols], `%in%`, bcde))
```

Comment: If I wanted to use the same code but instead of specifying certain columns, apply the function to all columns of my dataset, what would I write after "rowSums(across("?

Answer (score 1):

This could be also done in base R with axis wise `apply`, on `axis` `2`:

```
df$d9 <- rowSums(apply(df[cols], 2, `%in%`, bcde))
```

And now:

```
df
```

Gives:

```
  d1    d2    d3    d4    d5    d6    d7    d8       d9
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 b     a     a     a     a     a     a     a         0
2 a     a     a     a     c     a     a     a         1
3 a     b     a     a     a     a     a     a         1
4 a     a     c     a     a     b     a     a         2
5 a     a     a     a     a     a     a     a         0
6 a     a     b     a     a     a     a     a         1
7 a     a     a     a     a     d     a     a         1
8 a     a     a     d     a     a     a     a         1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dplyr-esque followed by an alternative using only dplyr:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  d1 = c('b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
  d2 = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
  d3 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'),
  d4 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'd'),
  d5 = c('a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
  d6 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'a'),
  d7 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
  d8 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a')
)

cols <- c('d2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6', 'd7', 'd8')
bcde <- c('b', 'c', 'd', 'e')

t(df) %>%
 as.data.frame() -> dft

dft[cols, ] %>% 
  map_dbl(~. %in% bcde %>% sum) %>%
  {mutate(df, d9 = .)}
#> # A tibble: 8 × 9
#>   d1    d2    d3    d4    d5    d6    d7    d8       d9
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 b     a     a     a     a     a     a     a         0
#> 2 a     a     a     a     c     a     a     a         1
#> 3 a     b     a     a     a     a     a     a         1
#> 4 a     a     c     a     a     b     a     a         2
#> 5 a     a     a     a     a     a     a     a         0
#> 6 a     a     b     a     a     a     a     a         1
#> 7 a     a     a     a     a     d     a     a         1
#> 8 a     a     a     d     a     a     a     a         1


#We can also do a `rowwise()` approach.

bcde_present <- function(x) {
  x %in% bcde 
}

#regular expression to match the desired columns in case they don't appear in order.

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(d9 = sum(bcde_present(across(matches('d[2-8]')))))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 9
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   d1    d2    d3    d4    d5    d6    d7    d8       d9
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1 b     a     a     a     a     a     a     a         0
#> 2 a     a     a     a     c     a     a     a         1
#> 3 a     b     a     a     a     a     a     a         1
#> 4 a     a     c     a     a     b     a     a         2
#> 5 a     a     a     a     a     a     a     a         0
#> 6 a     a     b     a     a     a     a     a         1
#> 7 a     a     a     a     a     d     a     a         1
#> 8 a     a     a     d     a     a     a     a         1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(d9 = across(all_of(cols), `%in%`, bcde) %>% 
        reduce(`+`))
# A tibble: 8 × 9
  d1    d2    d3    d4    d5    d6    d7    d8       d9
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 b     a     a     a     a     a     a     a         0
2 a     a     a     a     c     a     a     a         1
3 a     b     a     a     a     a     a     a         1
4 a     a     c     a     a     b     a     a         2
5 a     a     a     a     a     a     a     a         0
6 a     a     b     a     a     a     a     a         1
7 a     a     a     a     a     d     a     a         1
8 a     a     a     d     a     a     a     a         1
```